# WCF Consumer not attaching client credentials to header

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication

I have a WCF service that uses username authentication, I have a console app that consumes the service and attempts to access a protected method. I run the code and Fiddler says in the auth tab:

> No Proxy-Authorization Header is present.
>
> No Authorization Header is present.

Here is my accessing code:

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();

binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName;
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
binding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.Basic;
binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
binding.Security.Message.AlgorithmSuite = System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Default;
binding.Security.Transport.Realm = "MyRealm";         

ServiceReference1.MobileAPIClient serviceProxy = new ServiceReference1.MobileAPIClient(binding, new EndpointAddress("https://xx.xx.xx.xx/InventoryServices.MobileApi.svc"));

serviceProxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "test";
serviceProxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "test123";

serviceProxy.ChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "test";
serviceProxy.ChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "test123";

try 
{
    serviceProxy.Test();
}
catch (Exception ex) 
{
    var ex2 = ex;
}
```

Why are the credentials not being attached to the header?

Answer (score 0):

There is handshaking mode in wcf. So client and service exchange with credentials before first request and then they use only session token.
To disable this mode you should set in web.config

```
<security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" negotiateServiceCredential="false" establishSecurityContext="false"/>
</security>
```